# Send XML through PHP / Soap / WSDL with certificate

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, certificate

I'm completely blind about Soap and I need to connect to a soap/wsdl webservice with a certificate using this link [a link](https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl), send the XML file and get the response.
The XML is generated by a form and uploaded to the server.

I found and example here but I d'ont know how to use it (code below).
I know that I have to use "pem" file instead of "pfx" and I converted already following another examples.
I have generated, already, the XML (file below).
The settings for PHP / Soap Client are also ok at the server.
I'm using PHP LAMP with php 7.2.

Soap example:

```
function Curl_Soap_Request($request, $url)
{
    /**
     * @param request is your xml for soap request 
     * @param url is location of soap where your request with hit
     */

    $keyFile = getcwd() . "\\privatekey.pem"; //
    $caFile = getcwd() . "\\certificate.pem"; //
    $certPass = "test123";
    // xml post structure

    $xml_post_string = $request; // data from the form, e.g. some ID number

    $headers = array(
    "Content-type:  application/soap+xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    // "SOAPAction: '/Imp1/ApplicantEligibilityService",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_post_string),
    ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

    //$url = $soapUrl;

    // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // The --key option - If your key file has a password, you will need to set
    // this with CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD
    //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,  $keyFile);

    // The --cacert option
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,  $caFile);

    // The --cert option
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $certPass);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    // converting
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;

}
```

The XML that I need to sent:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.solicitacao.selodigital.tjce.jus.br/" xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<ser:solicitaSelos>
<arg0>
<cabecalho>
<versao>1.12</versao>
<dataHora>"2019-03-21T15:28:48.147306-03:00"</dataHora>
<ambiente>2</ambiente>
<serventia>
<codigoServentia>000321</codigoServentia>
</serventia>
</cabecalho>
<solicitante>
<nomePessoa></nomePessoa>
<documento>
<tipoDocumento>1</tipoDocumento>
</documento>
</solicitante>
<idSolicitacaoselo>4</idSolicitacaoselo>
<itens>
<itemSolicitacao>
<sequencial>1</sequencial>
<codigoSelo>
<codigo>14</codigo>
</codigoSelo>
<quantidade>1500</quantidade>
<sequencial>2</sequencial>
<codigoSelo>
<codigo>76</codigo>
</codigoSelo>
<quantidade>5000</quantidade>
</itemSolicitacao>
<itens>
</arg0>
</ser:solicitaSelos>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

#

Something new, I found this code for the conection but gives me the error below:

The code:

```
$local_cert = "../cert.pem";
$local_priv = "../private.key";
$wsdl = "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl";
$location = "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo";

$options = array(    
    'keep_alive'    => true,
    'trace'         => true,
    'location'      => $location,
    'local_cert'    => $local_cert,
    'local_priv'    => $local_priv,
    'passphrase'    => 'pass',
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);

try {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

The error:

> object(SoapFault)#2 (9) { ["message":protected]=> string(240)
>   "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   " ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=>
>   int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(65)
>   "/home/storage/a/7f/23/openselos/public_html/soap/teste/client.php"
>   ["line":protected]=> int(52) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1)
>   { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(65)
>   "/home/storage/a/7f/23/openselos/public_html/soap/teste/client.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(52) ["function"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["class"]=>
>   string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2)
>   { [0]=> string(78)
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   [1]=> array(7) { ["keep_alive"]=> bool(true) ["trace"]=> bool(true)
>   ["location"]=> string(73)
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo"
>   ["local_cert"]=> string(11) "../cert.pem" ["local_priv"]=> string(14)
>   "../private.key" ["passphrase"]=> string(4) "pass" ["cache_wsdl"]=>
>   int(0) } } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL
>   ["faultstring"]=> string(240) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load
>   from
>   'https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   " ["faultcode"]=> string(4) "WSDL" }

So, what is missing here????